# Box-Shadow not displaying IE 9-10

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a somehow complex submenu where i want to apply a box-shadow effect.

http://flytango.com.ar/test/test-lidherma.html

Scroll down for the menu

Works on Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc but it doesn't in ANY version of Internet Explorer

CSS

```
.grey ul.mega-menu li .sub-container {
position: absolute;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top:2px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
}
```

I've tryed the border-collapse solution but didn't work for me.

Any clues?

Comment: Update: It has something to do with the .sub-container class only. If I apply the styles to any other element, it does work. If i change the position:absolute to relative, it shows the box-shadows but the structure falls appart

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache, it works in IE9+. I tested it myself.

Comment: I've done that but still, im getting the error in two different pcs

Answer (score 0):

According to http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow, box-shadow is supported in IE9+

In which versions did you test?

Can you post a simplified version of your test case in jsfiddle.net ?

Here's a simplified version I did and the shadow does display (viewing this in IE10):
http://jsfiddle.net/GvehV/1/

```
<ul>
 <li>test</li>
</ul>

li {
position: absolute;
font-size: 18px;
padding-left: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #CCC;
}
```

I'm assuming you need to narrow down the problem to whatever element you're selecting with .sub-container. Does it have specific dimensions set, or some padding ?

Comment: If i change "position:absolute" to relative it works but of course the structure breaks off

Comment: 10 errors on [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fflytango.com.ar%2Ftest%2Ftest-lidherma.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Press F12 while in IE and click on the Console Tab:                  `HTML1524: Invalid DOCTYPE. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>". 
test-lidherma.html, line 1 character 1
HTML1521: Unexpected "</body>" or end of file. All open elements should be closed before the end of the document. 
test-lidherma.html, line 266 character 1`

Answer (score 0):

It's there, you just can't see it because the blur is set to 0.  Try `box-sizing: 0 2px 5px 2px #ccc` and you will see it.